# Is Bounded subspaces of R be homeomorphic to R?

Tags: real-analysis

Choose the correct statement(s):

(A) There is a continuous surjective function from [0, 1) to R;

(B) R and [0, 1) are homeomorphic to each other;

(C) There is a bijective function from [0, 1) to R;

(D) Bounded subspaces of R cannot be homeomorphic to R.

my answer : option1 is true  as  i take $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\sin\frac{1}{1-x}$$...

option2).  R and (0,1)  are homeormorphic so it   is false

option3) option 3 is false because R and [0, 1) are not  homeomorphic to each other so there is no bijection exist.

option 4) is True as subspace  $[0,1]∩R =[0,1]$ as $[0,1] $ is not homeomorphic to
 R.

is my answer is correct or not ...pliz verified and tell me the solution i will be glad and i woul be more thankful  .....
Thanks in advance

Comment: But for option $4$, you have already stated that $\Bbb R$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic, and $(0,1)$ is bounded.

Comment: Option 3 is true; homeomorphisms are very particular bijections. In general, a bijection does not need to be continuous.

Comment: Note for option $3$ that you don't need the function to be continuous.

Comment: In (B) I don't understand why you don't need to justify that $(0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1)$, while you do for $\Bbb R$. The logical gap is exactly the same.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedoim not getting ur statement......

Comment: @ Mundron Schmidt....how can it be possible that the only boubded subspace of R is {1}.  can u elabaorate ?

Comment: @Clayton  but the subspace is closed and bounded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A) Your example is correct.

(B) The statement is false, but your argument isn't valid. Suppose there exists a continuous bijection $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb R$. Fix the point $f(0)\in\mathbb R$. Now you can deduce that $f([0,1))\subset [f(0),\infty)$ or $f([0,1))\subset(-\infty,f(0)]$ (if not, use IVT to get a contadiction. Then, $f$ is not bijective.

(C) There is a bijection from $[0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$. But it is a bit tricky to define. There is a question somewhere here on stackexchange, but I don't find it. The idea is the following:

For $n\in\mathbb N$ define $f\left(1-\frac1n\right)=n$. Next, you define $f$ bijective $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ into $(-\infty,1)$ and $\left(\frac{k}{k+1},\frac{k+1}{k+2}\right)$ into $(k,k+1)$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.

(D) $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb R$-vectorspace is $1$-dimensional and has just the subspaces $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R$. $\{0\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ since its finite while $\mathbb R$ isn't. And $\mathbb R$ is not bounded.
If you are talking about subspaces in topological sense, then an example isn't enough to prove the statement that no bounded subspace of $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. But a counterexample proves that the statement is wrong. And in topological sense you can consider the subspace $(0,1)\subset \mathbb R$, which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: thanks a  lots ton times @Mundron Schmidt